# How do I protect an API?

Tags: web-services, web, security

I am currently working on a single-page web application. The web app will make calls to a REST-like API for authentication and data storage. We are currently in the middle of securing the application, and have worked out a strategy securing the site so only registered users can gain access. But one thing we also want to do is securing the API from others to write their own applications, or access it in any other way than through our web application. The problem from my view is that the API will be open for everybody and not only for my web application.

Anyone who knows how to do this, or who can point me in the right direction. Because right now, don't have a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Considered using certificates and validation?

Answer (score 0):

Your API should only be accessible, if the session of the client is authorized. That's pretty much anything you could do.

There are complex approaches like using client- and server-side encryption or something really basic: render a secret in your webpage that validates the user again on every request.
You could check the headers, where the original request comes from. And so on...

But as most of that is public in a users browser, anyone could read it and adopt it in a third party app.

So save yourself and the people that really want to do a third party app some time and provide a public API :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way will be to use  OAuth 2.0 ( supports both  authentication and authorization) which you need.

Also ensure you secure the data on wire using TLS (HTTPS) and any of the options below

```
1. HTTP Digest
2. OAuthn 2.0
3. Certificates ( Shared secret)
```

Stick to HTTPS+Oauth2 for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could lock down your you API to accept requests from known IP's. Also depending on how your network infrastructure is designed, your web application can sit in a DMZ and your API on an internal network accessible only by servers in your network, one of which will include your backend API (This article here info https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/5-common-server-setups-for-your-web-application has some tips). For better security, a secure network design in addition to an application security framework implementation like OAuth2 and HTTPS (mentioned above). For API's, I've found that resource based authorization works better than role based authorization. Lastly, constant review of your security setup is vital as things change all the time. A good approach to this is Threat Modelling described by OWASP here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Application_Threat_Modeling